# Trying to parse a JSON array in Unity C# but it returns null

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, jsonparser

Here is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "An item"
  }
 ]
```

Here is my helper class:

```
public static class JsonHelper
    {
        public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
        {
            string newJson = "{ \"array\": " + json + "}";
            Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(newJson);
            return wrapper.array;
        }

        [System.Serializable]
        private class Wrapper<T>
        {
            public T[] array;
        }
    }
```

Here is the class I am trying to make objects out of:

```
public class Item
{   
    public string name, desc;
}
```

This is where I am calling the helper class:

```
Item[] itemList = JsonHelper.FromJson<Item>(itemJson.text);
```

The problem is `itemList` and `wrapper.array` in `JsonHelper` is `null`.

I copied code directly from:

http://www.boxheadproductions.com.au/deserializing-top-level-arrays-in-json-with-unity/

and

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-load-an-array-with-jsonutility.375735/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unity's JSON implementation doesn't support unwrapped top-level arrays. You don't want to get into the habit of using them anyways, considering top-level JSON arrays have been the target of several security exploits over the years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you install `json.net` NuGet package for Unity by using below command in package manager console

```
Install-Package Unity.Newtonsoft.Json -Version 7.0.0
```

And then without modifying much of your code, you can get it to work

Just replace your `JsonHelper` class with below

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        string newJson = "{ \"array\": " + json + "}";
        JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(newJson);
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = jToken.ToObject<Wrapper<T>>();
        return wrapper.array;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] array;
    }
}
```

And you need to add `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` namespace to your program.

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

**Caution:** using Newtonsoft.Json does not work in WebGL projects.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what is wrong with the usage of Unity's official JSON library in my code?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code in your question but the unity Json library is a bit lacking, as is evident by its inability to support top-level arrays.

Comment: @HenryZhang, I think the above comment by **Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen** is right because your json is top-level array. and if my answer was help you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and vote up also :)

Comment: There are other things the built-in json utility can't do, either, such as a custom converter so you can serialize things in a non-standard way. Say, for example, in Minecraft I want to save out the world as blocks. I don't want to encode the entire `Block` class at each position! I want to encode merely a *reference* that I can look up during deserialization. Say, `"block_stone"` or `1`.

Comment: A word of caution - using Newtonsoft.Json does not work in WebGL projects.

Comment: You don't need to use an external library just for a wrapper... http://www.boxheadproductions.com.au/deserializing-top-level-arrays-in-json-with-unity/

Comment: this does not work if you have JSON that contains Vector3 and such `ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to UnityEngine.Vector3.`